Audio Lag Issue in Long-term FFmpeg Live Streaming with x11grab and Pulse
I am using FFMpeg to grab the desktop using x11grab. I am also using pulse for audio. However, in my FFMpeg output, the audio is ahead of the video. My arguments are:
"-hwaccel", "cuda",
"-f", "x11grab",

"-s", "1920x1080",

"-draw_mouse", "0",

"-thread_queue_size", "1024",

"-i", ":1",

"-f", "pulse",

"-r", "60",

"-thread_queue_size", "1024",

"-i", "VirtualSink.monitor",

"-c:v", "h264_nvenc",

"-preset:v", "hq",

"-b:v", "2500k",

"-maxrate", "2500k",

"-bufsize", "10000k",

"-vf", "fps=60,crop=1280:720:320:180,format=yuv420p",

"-g", "60",

"-c:a", "aac",

"-af", "adelay=900|900",

"-b:a", "128k",

"-ar", "44100",

"-fps_mode", "cfr",

"-async", "1",

"-f", "flv",

'RTMP_LINK',

After two days of streaming, the audio noticeably lags behind the video. I have tried adjusting various settings and buffers, but the issue persists.
Could anyone please provide any insights or suggestions on how to address this issue?
I have even tried restarting ffmpeg after every 24 hours but issue still persists.
I have also tried -copyopts with ffmpeg but AWS IVS has no output.
